# Cluster Analysis of customer behavior with geolocation data

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I want to cluster customers based on their buying behavior including where they shop at (latitude and longitude). I understand that HDBSCAN is good for lat/lon data. However, is it possible to include other kinds of attributes such as volume, average price of goods etc? I don't know if other algorithms would works well with this kind of "mixed" data.

Comment: note this style of question is discouraged from stackoverflow (due to lack of code and any obviously correct answer), you might get more useful responses from https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: apologies! I really wanted to start to write the code after the doubt was cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most clustering algorithms are defined for arbitrary numbers of features, this includes HDBSCAN.  only you'll know how well it works with your dataset!

a few obvious issues:

1. lat/long define a spherical coordinate system and hence you might need to do something special if you're expecting customers to span the globe.  e.g. +/-180 degrees longitude should be the "same", hence you'd probably need some way of encoding these as having a distance of zero.
2. normalisation is probably also going to be important, i.e. features should generally have the same mean and variance (mean=0 and sd=1 are common).  also, it's probably important to make sure things are from the appropriate distribution, e.g. maybe take the log of the price, and the sqrt of the volume, before normalising.

HDBSCAN lets you work with [distance matrices directly](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_hdbscan.html#distance-matrices) which might help with the first item